# How to route CURL through another IP address using CURL_SETOPT?

Tags: php, curl, woocommerce, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am using mailchimp plugin to connect my woocommerce site to their platform but my server's IP address is getting blocked by Akamai, a third party security layer that their API routes through. I have been told that the only way I can use mailchimp is to change the IP address that the API calls are going through. So now I'm trying to hack the plugin to do this. I believe what I need to do is use curl setopt but I have no idea how to use it within this code. Anyone have any ideas? I'm almost positive I put it in is this block of code somewhere but I don't know the proper syntax.

```
protected function put($url, $body)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    $json = json_encode($body);

    $options = $this->applyCurlOptions('PUT', $url, array(), array(
        'Expect:',
        'Content-Length: '.strlen($json),
    ));

    $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $json;

    curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);

    return $this->processCurlResponse($curl);
}
```

Comment: You need to change your server's IP address or use another server as a proxy.

Comment: I have another IP address available to use on my account (my host routes the frontend of my website through a dedicated IP so i want to use that one... the API calls are still coming from the original one) so i think it CAN be done my modifying this bit of code above

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to enable FREE cloudflare service on your website by signing up with CloudFlare. On activation of cloudflare your website IP will be atomatically changed to cloudflare proxy IP address and you will then find website IP via [**hostname to IP**](https://whatismyip.live/hostname-ip) and communicate with API without any need of changing your server IP.

Comment: I don't think this is the best solution at all